# Building Envoy WASM network filter

Tags: c++, rust, webassembly, envoyproxy

I'm trying to build a tcp level WASM filter for Envoy. I'm testing with following filter chain :

```
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.wasm
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.wasm.v3.Wasm
          config:
              name: "myfilter"
              vm_config:
                runtime: "envoy.wasm.runtime.v8"
                code:
                  local:
                    filename: "/opt/envoy/filter.wasm"
                allow_precompiled: true
      - name: envoy.filters.network.echo
```

my cpp code compiles ok and envoy starts fine, but even with just

```
FilterStatus MyFilterContext::onNewConnection() {
  LOG_DEBUG("onNewConn");
  return FilterStatus::StopIteration;
};
FilterStatus MyFilterContext::onDownstreamData(size_t, bool) {
  LOG_DEBUG("onDownstream");
  return FilterStatus::StopIteration;
}
```

I would expect the connection to never reach the echo service, yet it does every time, and there is nothing logged from wasm filter side in envoy logs, apart of trace level logs showing that wasm always returns the same logical value :

```
[29][trace][wasm] [source/extensions/common/wasm/wasm_vm.cc:40] [host->vm] proxy_on_new_connection(2)
[29][trace][wasm] [source/extensions/common/wasm/wasm_vm.cc:40] [host<-vm] proxy_on_new_connection return: 0
```

While there are many for HTTP filters, I was unable to locate any examples of a **network** filter implementation, which makes me wonder if anyone has this working, and if so, how exactly.

I also tried implementing it in rust, to no success as it compiles but then, within envoy it  fails with

```
Function: proxy_on_context_create failed: Uncaught RuntimeError: unreachable                    
Proxy-Wasm plugin in-VM backtrace:                                                                                                                                                       
  0:  0x164c - __rust_start_panic
```

Did anyone actually implemented a working **network** filter for Envoy ? An example code would be great as all the examples I found are for HTTP filters which do me no good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've implemented a working NETWORK_FILTER for Envoy. https://github.com/solo-io/proxy-runtime/commit/0b7fec73a36a979b53a05393b3868f1661af8dff was required for it to work in AssemblyScript. The commit message describes the YAML configuration I used with an Istio-flavored Envoy, but it depends on which version of Envoy you're using. Each language's runtime may or may not support it, but the C++ runtime certainly does, if you don't want to use AssemblyScript.

See also https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/network_filters/wasm_filter.html